# Date filter function with SQL doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, database, filter

I have a website where I load various activities who all have a specific date. I want to filter on those dates.

I do that with this query:

```
function selectAllActivities($date = false){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `activities`
            INNER JOIN `locations` on `activities`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`";
    if (!empty($date)){
        $sql .=  " WHERE `activities`.`start` >= :date AND `activities`.`start` < :next_day";
    }

    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':date', strtotime($date));
    $stmt->bindValue(':next_day', strtotime($date.'+1 day'));
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

If there is no date given, the page will load all the activities, but if someone wants to select a specific date to see which activities there are on that date, I use this code:

```
public function index() {
    $activityDAO = new ActivityDAO();

    if (!empty($_GET['date'])) {
        $activities = $activityDAO->selectAllActivities($_GET['date']);
    } else {
        $activities = $activityDAO->selectAllActivities();
    }
    $this->set('activities',$activities);
}
```

The page loading of all the activities is working fine, but if I select a specific date, the array with activities stays empty and no activities will load.

Comment: What does `$_GET['date']` look like? What datatype is the `activities.start` column?

Comment: Where is your error checking code

Comment: @RiggsFolly date = 'Y-m-d' and activities.start = 'Y-m-d-h-m'

Comment: Are you saying that the `activities.start` is a text datatype and NOT a DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP?

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh no sorry! It is a date datatype

Comment: try to convert $date to datetime : $mysql_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($source_date));

Comment: If its a DATE datatype then HOW can it contain `'Y-m-d-h-m'` ???

Comment: @RiggsFolly Datetime sorry to make you confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the column is Datetime , in your sql , you are injecting timestamp value , so that cause that yor result is always empty .

Instead , you can convert Date given to datetime with the same format *'Y-m-d-h-m'* using [gmdate](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.gmdate.php):

```
 function selectAllActivities($date = false){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `activities`
                INNER JOIN `locations` on `activities`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`";
        if (!empty($date)){
            $sql .=  " WHERE `activities`.`start` >= :date AND `activities`.`start` < :next_day";
        }
        $dateTime = gmdate("Y-m-d-h-m", strtotime($date));
        $dateTimeTomorrow=gmdate("Y-m-d-h-m", strtotime($date.'+1 day'));
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':date', $dateTime);
        $stmt->bindValue(':next_day', $dateTimeTomorrow);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

Comment: getting this error: Call to a member function format() on string

Comment: did you try the second solution ?

Comment: i'm gonna editing my answer leting only the second option